# Java/Android: convert String to bytes[] then to float and back

Tags: java, android, google-maps, polygon

I need to store the name of a polygone that I am drawing on a map. All my polygones have a name but the GoogleMap API doesn't allow you to put your own id on the polygone (someone please explain why ?! this does not make any sense !!) the only way to identify a polygone by an id would therefore be to keep a sort of ID in its z-index. The z-index is a float number and my id's are strings. I am therefore trying to convert my string to a bytes[] then to float, and the decode it when I need to identify my polygones. Here is how I am trying to do that:

```
 private float convertStringToFloat(ZoneData zone) {
        byte[] stringinBytes = zone.getName().getBytes();
        return ByteBuffer.wrap(stringinBytes).getFloat();
    }

    private String convertFloatToString(float nameFloat) {
        Float f = new Float(nameFloat);
        byte[] nameBytesArray =  new byte [] { (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 56),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 48),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 40),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 32),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 24),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 16),
                (byte) (f.byteValue() >>> 8),
                (byte) f.byteValue() };
        return new String(nameBytesArray);
    }
```

Unfortunately it just does not work and I am unsure why, when I print the output string I get a this:

```
[����������������, ����������������]
```

Once again I just do not understand why is there no way to identify the polygones is the API, if anyone form Google read this in what world would we want to draw polygones but not be able to identify them ?!

**UPDATE**

Here is how my ZoneData code works:

```
public class ZoneData {
    private LatLng P1;
    private LatLng P2;
    private LatLng P3;
    private LatLng P4;
    private String name;

    public ZoneData(JSONObject zone){
        patients = new ArrayList<PatientData>();
        try {
            this.name = zone.getString("name");
            this.P1 = new LatLng(zone.getDouble("P1Lat"), zone.getDouble("P1Lon"));
            this.P2 = new LatLng(zone.getDouble("P2Lat"), zone.getDouble("P2Lon"));
            this.P3 = new LatLng(zone.getDouble("P3Lat"), zone.getDouble("P3Lon"));
            this.P4 = new LatLng(zone.getDouble("P4Lat"), zone.getDouble("P4Lon"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public LatLng getP1() {
        return P1;
    }

    public void setP1(LatLng p1) {
        P1 = p1;
    }

    public LatLng getP2() {
        return P2;
    }

    public void setP2(LatLng p2) {
        P2 = p2;
    }

    public LatLng getP3() {
        return P3;
    }

    public void setP3(LatLng p3) {
        P3 = p3;
    }

    public LatLng getP4() {
        return P4;
    }

    public void setP4(LatLng p4) {
        P4 = p4;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you seem to be trying to treat a `float` as if it has 64 bits of information. Next, you're calling `f.byteValue()` and trying to treat *that* as if it has 64 bits of information. Fundamentally, I very much doubt that this approach is going to work.

Comment: I don't think anyone from Google is going to read this ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use and hashmap to store association between ZoneData id and polyline id:

```
HashMap<String,String> myIds = new HashMap<>();

Polyline polyline = map.addPolyline(...);
myIds.put(polyline.getId(),zone.getName();
```

and with color:

Polyline line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
     .width(5)
     .color(Color.RED));

Comment: How would that work ? ZoneData is an object with loads of other values inside of it, I updated my question with the code from zoneData

Comment: when I try to extend from Polyline I get this error: cannot inherit from final 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline'

Comment: yea that works the problem with using polylines is that I cant fill them with a colour and I would really need to do that. But good answer thanks !

Comment: I cannot get the point of the color...btw I have updated the answer with color too.

Comment: this adds color to the line not to the filling of the "polygon" or the inside of the polyline which is what i would need.

Comment: Instead of Polyline use Polygon so you can set fill color